# Rake test fail assert_match

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am following [Agile Web Developement with rails4](http://intertwingly.net/projects/AWDwR4/checkdepot/section-13.1.html)
and at the rake test I get this failure.
I cant figure out what's wrong... I know this causes the problem 
 **`assert_match /<td>1&times;<\/td>\s*<td>Programming Ruby 1.9<\/td>/,
       mail.body.encoded`**
 My [order_notifier_test](https://github.com/vasspilka/depot_rails4/blob/master/test/mailers/order_notifier_test.rb), my `shipped.text.erb` is under app/views/order_notifier

The failure 
`OrderNotifierTest#test_shipped [Work/depot/test/mailers/order_notifier_test.rb:17]:

Expected /<td>1&times;<\/td>\s*<td>Programming Ruby 1.9<\/td>/ to match "<h3>Pragmatic Order Shipped</h3>\r\n<p>\r\n  This is just to let you know that we've shipped your recent order:\r\n</p>\r\n \r\n<table>\r\n  <tr><th colspan=\"2\">Qty</th><th>Description</th></tr>\r\n 1 x Programming Ruby 1.9\r\n\r\n</table>\r\n".`

Feel free to browse the repository for more info (My system is there also under the README.md)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [failed assertion](https://github.com/vasspilka/depot_rails4/blob/728da3225b91ed90d838808772b6155848086de4/test/mailers/order_notifier_test.rb#L17):

```rb
assert_match /<td>1&times;<\/td>\s*<td>Programming Ruby 1.9<\/td>/, mail.body.encoded
```

is expecting the rendered view in HTML format (`line_items/_line_item.html.erb`).

However, since the mailer view is in text format (`order_notifier/shipped.text.erb`), the partial in it is also rendered in text format (`line_items/_line_item.text.erb`).

Therefore, you might want to change the assertion to:

```rb
assert_match /1 x Programming Ruby 1.9/, mail.body.encoded
```

(Just like the one in the previous received order notifier test.)

Answer (score 0):

i added

```
.gsub("\r\n", "")
```

to assert string:

```
assert_match /<td>1&times;<\/td>\s*<td>Programming Ruby 1\.9<\/td>/, mail.body.encoded.gsub("\r\n", "")
```